# Removing leading whitespace using VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to remove `leading whitespace` from a word `"   00000000000000231647300000000002KK"`.

Below is my `VBA` code

```
Option Explicit

Sub myfunction()
    Dim getarray, getarray1 As Variant
    Dim Text As String
    Dim RegularText
    getarray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value
    getarray1 = getarray
    Set RegularText = New regexp
    RegularText.Global = True
    RegularText.MultiLine = True
    RegularText.Pattern = "(^\\s+)"
    Text = CStr(getarray(1, 1))
    getarray1(1, 1) = RegularText.Replace(getarray(1, 1), "")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B4").Value = getarray1
End Sub
```

However above code fails to remove the `leading whitespace` from my word.

Below is the `excel workbook` with result and above code
https://easyupload.io/jv6n2p

If you could help to understand why my code is failing to remove `leading whitespace`, it will be very helpful.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Maybe it is easier to use `trim`-like function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions

Comment: Try `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").replace " ", ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the original code.

> ```
>  RegularText.Pattern = "(^\\s+)"
> ```

Explanations from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

### `(^\\s+)` pattern:

[image: Explanation of regular expression (^\\s+) from RegEx101.com]

Basically, the first backslash is escaping the second backslash.  This tells the RegEx to treat the second `\` as a normal character.  `(^\\s+)` is grouping leading `\s` characters together not whitespace.

### `(^\s+)` pattern:

[image: Explanation of regular expression (^\s+) from RegEx101.com]

> ```
>  RegularText.MultiLine = True
> ```

The `MultiLine` property indicates every line in a value should be searched not row in an array. This doesn't seem to be the intended result. So set it to false.

> ```
> `RegularText.MultiLine = False`
> ```

`Range("A1:A4").Value` is 1 row by 4 columns and `Range("B1:B4")` is 1 column by 4 rows.  In my examples I will use `Range("A2:D2")` for simplicity.

```
Sub RegExRemoveTrailingSpace()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value
    
    Dim RegularText As New RegExp
    RegularText.Global = False
    
    RegularText.Pattern = "(^\s+)"
    [b4] = RegularText.Replace([A1], "")
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(r, c) = RegularText.Replace(Data(r, c), "")
        Next
    Next
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2").Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

We could just use `LTrim()` to remove the leading spaces from the string.

```
Sub LTrimTrailingSpace()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(r, c) = LTrim(Data(r, c))
        Next
    Next
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D2").Value = Data
    
End Sub
```